# Logstash - How to use variable instead of hardcoded values in conditional if statement?

Tags: conditional-statements, logstash

I have conditional `IF` like this:

```
if ([mesage] =~ /(CRITICAL|ERROR)/) {
     add_field => { "priority" => "critical" }
} else {
    add_field => { "priority" => "low" }
}
```

How to get those values from field?
I tried below option but this did not worked.

```
add_field => { "priorityMessages" => "CRITICAL|ERROR" }
if ([mesage] =~ /([priorityMessages])/) {
     add_field => { "priority" => "critical" }
} else {
    add_field => { "priority" => "low" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add_field needs to be part of a filter (and is only triggered when that filter exists).   Try this:

```
if [message] =~ /(CRITICAL|ERROR)/) {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "priority" => "critical" }
    }
}
```

The better practice, though, is to use grok to pull fields out of your unstructured [message] field.